# Variables not updating synchronously

Tags: javascript

I keep running into this problem. And right now it has to do with the `Date` object

```
var now = new Date();
var later = new Date();
later.setHours( later.getHours() + 8 );

<Wait for somthing>
now = later;
later.setHours( later.getHours() + 8 );

alert(now == later); //returns True
```

I thought this could be solved using callbacks:

```
var adjustTime = function(callback){
     now = later;
     callback();
}
adjustTime(function(){
    later.setHours( later.getHours() + 8 );
});

alert(now == later); //returns True
```

What do I not understand? How can I update these variables correctly?

**EDIT:**
Ok, I should explained myself a bit better. What I want to do is to update the now variable to be the **value** of later. And after that I want to increase later with 8 hours.

Comment: What is 'wait for something'?

Comment: Can you explain more what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I think you're just expecting behavior different from the way JavaScript actually works. The examples you gave are not at all surprising to someone experienced with JavaScript.  Perhaps you could explain what you expected to happen and why the actual behavior is confusing you.

Comment: Also that callback example will result in a runtime exception, because you're not actually passing a function to the "adjustTime" routine. It makes no difference however because after setting a variable to the value of another, they'll be equal, as your `alert()` demonstrates.

Comment: OK I updated my answer - the key is that you need to create a brand new `Date` object for either "now" or "later".

Comment: About the callback, my initial thought was that `later` was updated before the assignment of `now`. But I don,t really see how this would result in a runtime error. If it would have been necessary, how am I supposed to pass a function to "adjustTime"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Equality comparisons between `Date` instances just tests for object reference equality.  And in any case, once you've done this:

```
now = later;
```

then the variables "now" and "later" reference the same object. Updates to "later" are therefore updates to "now".

The "setter" methods on the `Date` prototype all modify the object directly. That is, `Date` instances are not immutable.

*edit* — I'm going to guess that what you really want is to keep "now" and "later" separate. In that case, something like this is probably what you want:

```
now = later;
later = new Date(later.getTime());
later.setHours(later.getHours() + 8);
```

After that, "now" and "later" won't be equal because you'll have set it to a *new* `Date` instance.

Comment: Perfect. I guess it was the reference part that confused me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

After `now = later;` change in later will reflect in now and vise-verse. as both are same object

```
   var now = new Date();
    var later = new Date();
    later.setHours( later.getHours() + 8 );

    <Wait for somthing>
    now = later; //  now and later have refeerence of same object 
    later.setHours( later.getHours() + 8 );

    alert(now == later); //returns True
```

Comment: You just copied and pasted the code example with an added comment. Can you explain your answer? If you modify `later` by calling `setHours()`, why are they still equal?